# Delete font file in .NET (VB)

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone knows how to delete a font file in the C:\Windows\Font ?
I set the current user as the owner and set the access rule as FullControl but still run into `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception

```
        Dim fileS As FileSecurity = touninstall(ui).GetAccessControl
        Dim idref As SecurityIdentifier = fileS.GetOwner(GetType(SecurityIdentifier))
        Dim NTAccount As NTAccount = idref.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
        Console.WriteLine(NTAccount)

        'Update it, Grant Current User Full Control
        Dim cu As SecurityIdentifier = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User
        NTAccount = cu.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
        Console.WriteLine(NTAccount)
        fileS.SetOwner(cu)
        fileS.SetAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

        'Update the Access Control on the File
        touninstall(ui).SetAccessControl(fileS)

        'Delete the file            
        touninstall(ui).Delete()
```

I am running the app as admin. I think it has something to do with folder/file permissions and inheritance but not really sure.

Thanks

Comment: Which function call is causing the exception?  I suspect that you don't have Write access to the Fonts folder.  A better question might be why do you need to delete a font in the first place?

Comment: @dwilliss `touninstall(ui).Delete()` is the one causing the exception

Comment: and I do have write access indeed, as I can do it manually